# Important question regarding cofinite topology

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, real-numbers

We are saying for set $X$ is given topology $\delta$ if it is given  some family $\delta$ of subsets $U_i$ of $X$ and 3 axioms are true.

1)$X,\emptyset \in \delta$

2)The union of any number of elements of $\delta$ belongs to $\delta$

3)The intersection of any two elements of $\delta$ belongs to $\delta$

And elements of $\delta$ are called open sets.

Now question is about finding closure of $(a,b)$ in cofinite topology $\Bbb R$.

Closure of set $M$ is intersection of closed sets that contain $M$.

Now how can closure of $(a,b)$ in cofinite topology($\Bbb R$) be $\Bbb R$?

Because we want to find closure of cofinite topology in $\Bbb R$ first of all $\Bbb R$ must be subset of topology by definition so $\Bbb R$ is open set. If $\Bbb R$ is open set how it can be closure because closure is intersection of closed sets?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, $\Bbb R$ is an open set. Nonetheless, it is also a closed set (the whole space is *always* a closed set for *any* topology) and, with respect to the co-finite topology, it is the smallest closed set that contains $(a,b)$. Therefore $\overline{(a,b)}=\Bbb R$.

Comment: How one would prove that $R$ is also closed set in co-finite topology?

Comment: Because $\Bbb R\setminus\Bbb R=\emptyset$, which is an open set.

Comment: @unit1991 . In topology the entire space is always both open and closed. as $phi$ the null set always has to be inside the topology. Also the null set is both open and closed.

Comment: Yes @Mr.GandalfSauron at topology class we didn't say that entire space is always both closed and open.It is theorem that we need to prove? Or we accept that fact by definition?

Comment: Well since $\phi$ and $X$ are always in the topology $\delta$ . Then they are always open . So their complements are closed.

Comment: Mr.Gandalf Sauron Thank you!

Comment: I have one more question regarding your answer @José Carlos Santos.How prove that $R$ is smallest closed set that contains $(a,b)$?

Comment: @user 1991: The only closed sets in the cofinite topology are finite and $\mathbb{R}$. (You can verify this with the complement theorem for open and closed sets.) Since $(a,b)$ is infinite, the entire space is the only option.

Comment: Because $(a,b)$ is an infinite set, and therefore any set containing $(a,b)$ is also infinite, and therefore it is not closed (unless it is the whole space).

Comment: The closure is the smallest closed set containing A .

Comment: I have two really good answers and I don't know which one to accept.

Comment: @unit1991 You can try to prove what I said about cofinite topology on infinite sets. The proof will be the same as I did.

Comment: @Mr.GandalfSauron Thanks I'll try.

Answer (score 1):

For every open set $O$ in a topology $(X, \mathcal T)$, we form its complement. These sets together are called the closed sets of$X$. So $\emptyset = X^\complement$ and $X = \emptyset^\complement$ are closed sets ( in any topology). If $O$ is any other open set in the cofinite topology, by definition $O^\complement$ is finite and conversely any finite subset is the complement of an open set and so itself closed.

So all closed sets for the cofinite topology are: all finite sets (including $\emptyset$) plus $X$. So if $A$ is any infinite set it only has **one** closed superset namely $X$. So the closure of $A$ is $X$, there are no other candidates.

Answer (score 0):

$(a,b)$ itself is infinite.

Any open set is of the form $\mathbb{R}\setminus F$ where $F$ is some finite set.

So you can see that any open set only excludes atmost finitely many elements of $(a,b)$. So any point is a limit point of the set $(a,b)$.

So $\overline{(a,b)}=\mathbb{R}$.

Also for any infinite subset of a infinite space , the set of limit points will be the entire space under cofinite topology

Also I would like to reword your definition:-

A collection of sets $\delta$ is called a topology over a set $X$ if :-

1. $X\in \delta$
2. Arbitrary union of open sets is always open . (The members of $\delta$ are called open sets).
3. Intersection of finite number of open sets is open .( Or equivalently , intersection of two open sets is open. Hence you can proceed inductively and conclude that intersections of finite number of open sets is open).

Now as to your question why $X$ and $\phi$ are closed.

By definition of topology $X$ is open hence $X\setminus X = \phi$ is closed.
And $\phi$ is open , so $X\setminus \phi=X$ is closed.

Comment: "Also for any infinite subset of a infinite space , the set of limit points will be the entire space." - This isn't true for a general infinite topological space. If you are specifically talking about the cofinite topology here, you should clarify so as to not confuse others.